# Limits of Windows 10 Network Mapping via WebDAV

Tags: windows, webdav, nextcloud

Our Nextcloud instance is hosted by Hetzner, and we need to map the nextcloud drive to a local Windows drive for a third party software that relies on drive letters to function. Therefore, I mapped the nextcloud drive to a WebDAV drive using the default Windows tools.

Everything seems fine as the drive is showing up and we can access it as well as the files on it.
BUT we have one directory with >50000 files in it.
We can open the directory with the also locally installed Nextcloud client as well as online.
But when we try to open the directory using the WebDAV drive in Windows Explorer, it stops working and says we can't open it. This is, in fact, incorrect, as we can open it using other methods, such as the client or the web interface.

So long story short:

- Is there a maximum number of files which can be handeled by windows over a WebDAV connection?

Comment: welcome, split the folder. and look into the logs of the Webservers

Comment: which webservers? the webserver hosting the nextcloud? I have no easy access to this machine and it's logfiles as it is managed by hetzner.

Comment: But then in fact, the question is off topic. The reason is that home and enduser computing questions can and should be asked on superuser.com instead. Create a ticket with Hetzner, they will explain the reason, but I think 50k files are in violation of the maximum runtime. Furthermore, even with a normal local running Explorer, 50k files will be a real headache. As suggested, I believe the issue will resolve itself if you split the Folder into smaller parts.